# Inductor saturation current

Tags: current, pwm, inductor, buck, waveform

I'm trying to determine an inductor's saturation current, I use a PWM with a gate driver (TLP250) and a 0.4Ω sense resistor at the source which I probe across to capture the current waveform.

I salvaged the inductor from a 2 amp buck circuit (which means it can handle the current, I hope), however, the waveform is something I can't understand, I'd appreciate a good explanation of what might be going on in the circuit.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is this waveform? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Do you understand what happens when an inductor saturates? What its behavior will be? This behavior will result in a very large current in your circuit. I would take measures to limit that current to prevent things blowing up.

Comment: Thanks, I added the waveform photo..

Comment: And yes, current is already limited by the source.

Comment: Is the sense resistor 0.4 or 0.5Ohm? Assuming the peak voltage is 3V across a 0.5 Ohm resistor, the saturation current is 6A. It also means the drain is at 3V. You’ve not stated which mosfet you’ve used but it is probably not happy with a Vgs of 2V and starts to oscillate.

Comment: Im using an IRF530, Rs is 0.4 Ohm, i thought the tlp250 takes care of the gate driving regardless of the voltage at the source, also the waveform shown is when the current was about 2 Amps, and the current can go up to my PS limit when i adjust the duty cycle with no problems.

Comment: The ringing suggests you may have fried your diode. I would check it.

Comment: The diode checks fine ..

Comment: In my previous comment i mention drain then go on and use Vgs. I did mean source. How does the TLP250 anticipate the voltage on the source? It doesn’t. The scope says it supplies 5V to the gate. According to the irf530 datasheet, it can switch around 3A at 5V Vgs. You might have a different result driving the gate with 12V.

Comment: In the photo, I assume the current is the yellow trace? What's the blue trace? Also, what diode are you using? Having worked with circuits of this type in the past for evaluating parts, it can matter a lot whether you use a FRED, a Schottky, or a standard diode. Though I don't know if that would affect things when trying to measure the *inductor*...